# How to open a file (inside function) provided by function parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python 3 at the moment, and I have a problem with opening a file provided as a function parameter.

This is my code:

```
def make_list_from_file(file_name):

    with open(file_name,"r") as provided_file:
        temp_list = [line.strip() for line in provided_file]
    detailed_list = [ item.split("\t") for item in temp_list ]
    return detailed_list

make_list_from_file(game_stat.txt)
```

This gives me:

```
NameError: name 'Game_Stat' is not defined.
```

The file is in the same directory. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: pass a string to the function, like this `make_list_from_file("game_stat.txt")`

Comment: look at the `csv` module from the stdlib!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
make_list_from_file(game_stat.txt)
```

strings should be enclosed with single (') or double (") quotes.

So:

```
make_list_from_file("game_stat.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
with open(file_name,"r") as provided_file:
```

to :

```
with open(file_name + '.txt',"r") as provided_file:
```